# Classical RPG Item Handling

Tags: c#, structure

How to structure items (as there are different types of items) in an organized and ease-to-manage way.

My idea is to have an ItemManager that loads all items and stores them. However, this is were I am unsure. Only weapons have a mininum and maximum damage. Only armors have armor. Should I really be storing them all as Item?

With heritage I can solve that (I think!).

**ItemManager.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class ItemManager : MonoBehaviour {

    private static List<Item> items;

    public ItemManager () {
        items = new List<Item> ();
    }

    void Awake () {     
        DontDestroyOnLoad (this);

        // load all items from file
    }

    public static int Length {
        get {return items.Count;}
    }

    public static Item Item (int index) {
        return items [index];
    }
}
```

**Item.cs**

```
using UnityEngine; // only used for debug purposes

public class Item : MonoBehaviour { // : MonoBehaviour are for debug purposes

    private string _name;
    private string _desc;

    private int _maxQuantity; // quest items wont have one

    private int _category;
    private bool _dropable; // quest items wont have one
    private int _price; // quest items wont have one

    public Item () {
        _name = string.Empty;
        _desc = string.Empty;

        _quantity = 0;
        _maxQuantity = 0;

        _category = 0;
        _dropable = false;
        _price = 0;
    }

#region Setters and Getters
    public string Name {
        get {return _name;}
        set {_name = value;}
    }

    public string Desc {
        get {return _desc;}
        set {_desc = value;}
    }

    public int MaxQuantity {
        get {return _maxQuantity;}
        set {_maxQuantity = value;}
    }

    public int Category {
        get {return _category;}
        set {_category = value;}
    }

    public bool Dropable {
        get {return _dropable;}
        set {_dropable = value;}
    }

    public int Price {
        get {return _price;}
        set {_price = value;}
    }
#endregion
}

// enum used to identify categories by name
public enum ItemCategory {
    Miscellaneous,
    Quest,
    Consumable,
    Weapon,
    Armor,
    Gem,
    Resource,
};
```

I generally (try to!) use _ as a prefix when the variable have a getter and/or setter.

Storing the "instances" of the items will be done on character/party level. Holding the *Item* and *Quantity*.

With this as a start I have to many problems of how to handle the actual storing and accessing of the variables.

How do I actually wrap the item storing and loading process up?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I took it http://codereview.stackexchange.com is when you have code to be reviewed? I don't, I need to know how to actually implement the code for it to work.

Comment: just do it and you'll see.

Comment: @KonradKokosa: I figured CR.SE is for working code only.

Answer (score 1):

> Only weapons have a mininum and maximum damage. Only armors have armor. Should I really be storing them all as Item?

You can define another class for `Weapons` and `Armors` that inherit from `Item` class.Make your `Item` class `abstract`,and define common properties inside of it.

And just to get and set a variable you don't need a property like this:

```
public string Desc {
    get {return _desc;}
    set {_desc = value;}
}
```

Instead use [auto-implemented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) properties if you don't have a different logic when you getting and setting your value:

```
public string Desc { get; set; }
```

Comment: In my item manager then I should be having a list per category of item? On armor and weapon I should save which slot they belong to? For example if I have a helm or an cloak I would store that in the armor class?

Comment: @Emz, you can store Armors and Weapons into List<Item> because they will inherit from Item class,in you process function check for item's type with GetType method,if it's Armor then cast it to Armor `(Armor)item` like that.then you can do what you want.

Comment: I have 2 items, Sword and Helm, Sword has 2 damage. Helm has 2 armor. Should I do the following; `ItemWeapon weapon = new ItemWeapon();` `weapon.damage = 2;` `items.Add(weapon);`. Then to get the damage I will be using typecast (with an if check I presume)? How will damage fit inside my items list?

Comment: It will take a bit more time than I thought to make a decision it seems, but I thank you for adding another layer of information. I will get back and accept the answer (if I pick it) once I decide for one. I'd hope there was a magic potion that solved all my problems. Why don't I have more time?--

Answer (score 1):

I would go with Interfaces: One base interface for common stuff like ID, name etc. and others Interfaces for Weapons / armor etc.
Then you can test at runtime which interfaces are implemented an can act accoridngly (i.e. display damage or armor value).
The main benefit over inheritance is the easiness of composition and the possibillity to do duck-typing, e.g. have something which is a chair AND a weapon at need.

Comment: I read two articles on how to implement interfaces that supports duck-typing, it seems to be about the same in the base as inheritance? With the difference that I store the items in different lists depending on their type?

Comment: NO, you are not storing the items in different lists. You have one List<Item> which contains all things that are like an item. Some Items have an Interface which describes other behaviour like damage etc. When the user picks such an item, qou can do additional actions depending on the exact interface(s):

Comment: As a tipp: do read HEad first Design patterns - it really helps which such concepts.

Comment: http://www.jtbookyard.com/uploads/6/2/9/3/6293106/head_first_design_pattern.pdf That one at 654 pages?

Comment: It never occured to me that one even could buy it, that link was the first thing I found. However thanks, I will read it. Which means it will take a bit more time than I thought to make a decision, but I thank you for adding another layer of information. I will get back and accept the answer (if I pick it) once I decide for one. I'd hope there was a magic potion that solved all my problems. Why don't I have more time?--

Comment: Because we never have enough time ;)
As a suggestion after a good nights sleep: Maybe you could use inheritance for base functionality (everything in the inventory inherits from the item class), but advanced behaviour is implemented as Interface. But I am unsure if it is really a good idea to implement this in isolation from the rest of the game. E.g. What class has an item in the world and which one in the inventory?

Comment: My initial idea is to save all items in my item manager class, then save the items a player have in their inventory resp. the item the enemy/enemies will drop in their inventory.